# Is there integrity check in PE files?

Tags: windows, exe, reverse-engineering, portable-executable, integrity

I am trying to edit some portable executable file with text editor.
In the top of the file a backward compatibility string is supposed to display messages on DOS systems.

[`This program cannot be run in DOS mode.`(click the link to see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r8JD.png)

I first tried to edit this string by replacing a char (not removing or adding : just replacing to not change the file size). Then when I try to execute the file windows return an error saying I can't run this app on my computer.

I also tried to edit the padding at the very end of the file and the error is the same.

I suppose an integrity check is performed. Did someone already read about this?  If you did, do you know if/where the file hash is stored in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A text editor is not appropriate for editing binary files. Use a hex editor instead.

Comment: It worked fine with a hexeditor.
Next time I won't be so lazy and I will install it from the beginning.
Thx & have a nice day :)

Comment: @MaxBuridant Just to add to Norbert's answer, PE files can also be signed which prevent any modifications (see [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#certificate-data) or search for PE authenticode).

Comment: There's also a checksum in PE headers, see IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32/IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 CheckSum filed docs.